# Is it possible to play AAA video games with an external SSD?

Tags: ssd, gaming

I've been using a laptop to play AAA video games, but the SSD is getting full. It has two USB-C/thunderbolt ports, so I'm wondering if there are downsides of installing games on an external SSD. So far I've found USB-C external SSD's, but am having trouble finding one that includes thunderbolt.

My question is, will a USB-C SSD play games basically on par with an internal SSD? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

USB 3.0, which most systems support, has a data rate of 5Gbps.  This is slightly slower than the latest SATA revision which is 6Gpbs.  NVMe is even faster.

There's a lot of factors that come into play with storage device speed at any given moment; the above would be theoretical maximums.

However any speed difference between the above is unlikely to be significant enough to affect gaming,  It would be a concern for things like multiuser network database access; if you are running a database server along with your games then this is a concern but if you are only playing games on this system, it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: Agreed.  Generally, modern games arent disk bound, so once they are loaded, you typically do not notice disk access, unless you are moving into a new area with a new map and textures.  However, even then, some developers have gotten smart and will preload textures and environments before you get there, so you might not even notice it.

Comment: While USB 3.1, is either 5Gbps Or 10Gbps. But seriously, whether the bridge is a UAS one matters much more, especially for random I/O.